# Pointer reference?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pointers

I'm pretty new to iPhone application development and I'm doing well so far. But at one point my App doesn't do what it is intend for...
It's a tableview based app and i'm pushing a new controller onto the stack to get some Userinput, but when the controller is popped again the data is somehow gone. Perhaps I've missunderstood something with the pointers??

`rootviewcontroller.m:`

```
edit = [fields objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
listView.element = edit;
[self.navigationController pushViewController: listView animated:YES];
```

`ListView.m:`

```
element.value = [list objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

so what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

edit:

the value field is shown in the tableview with the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
UILabel *title = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *detail = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:2];
ListElement *l = [fields objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
title.text = l.name;
detail.text = l.value;
```

Comment: What data is gone? The object that you assigned to element.value has been released or what?

Comment: well i want to read the object which is assinged to element.value in the ListView.m in rootviewcontroller.m in edit.value...

Comment: How do you tell hat the data is gone_ Don't you just see it or in the rootview or is it *really* not in edit.value (shown by logging or debugging)?

Comment: The code you have looks good. I think you need to provide more information. When/where are you trying to use edit.value and how is it not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is "gone" means "it's not shown after returning to root view" it can probably be fixed by

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

put into RootViewController.